# How to setup Hibernate Gradle plugin for bytecode enhancement?

Tags: hibernate, gradle

Hibernate Gradle plugin is an equivalent of `hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin` and offers build-time code enhancements. The [official docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html#_gradle_plugin) do not mention the `apply plugin: 'something'` line. If I just do as the guide says I get:

> Could not find method hibernate() for arguments...

I tried guessing the plugin name with `apply plugin: 'enhance'` (as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627000/how-to-enable-hibernate-build-time-bytecode-enhancement-before-intellij-idea-run) suggests) and `apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'` (as [this test](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/hibernate-gradle-plugin/src/test/groovy/org/hibernate/orm/tooling/gradle/HibernatePluginTest.groovy) suggests) but it just says the plugin with that id is unknown.

Has anyone managed to set this plugin up successfully?

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
allprojects {
    group 'xxx'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

project(':xxx-model') {
    buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenLocal()
           mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.0.7.Final"
       }
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'

    hibernate {
        enhance {}
    }
}

... more unrelated project blocks here
```

Experimented with moving the `buildscript{...}` into the root, `allprojects` and `subprojects` with no useful results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'
```

The plugin code indicates what you got from the test is correct. What you may be missing is a `repositories` section inside your `buildScript` section, to fetch the plugin jar from.

Comment: I've actually tried this as well and just got  "Plugin with id... not found". Do you maybe see anything misconfigured in my gradle.build? I'll give it another go in the meantime.

Comment: Where in your build.gradle are you putting `apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'` ?

Comment: It works if and only if I place the whole plugin config into sub-project's build.gradle. If the plugin config is in the root build.gradle under `project(':xxx-model')`, as exemplified in the question, it says the plugin is not found. Btw, I edited the question to show where I normally would put `apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'`

Comment: Note that we can use the newer plugins syntax when https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13354 is resolved.

Answer (score 17):

### For Gradle

A complete example looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:$hibernateVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'

hibernate {
    enhance {
        enableLazyInitialization= true
        enableDirtyTracking = true
        enableAssociationManagement = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion'
}
```

### For Maven

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After you set the enhance plugin, Hibernate recompiles the entity classes and changes the bytecode [like this](https://vladmihalcea.com/maven-gradle-hibernate-enhance-plugin/):

```
public void setDetails(PostDetails details) {
    this.$$_hibernate_write_details(details);
}
 
public void $$_hibernate_write_details(PostDetails details) {
    if (!Objects.deepEquals(details, this.details)) {
        this.$$_hibernate_trackChange("details");
    }
 
    this.details = details;
}

public void $$_hibernate_trackChange(String property) {
    if (this.$$_hibernate_tracker == null) {
        this.$$_hibernate_tracker = new SimpleFieldTracker();
    }
 
    this.$$_hibernate_tracker.add(property);
}
```

The `$$_` methods are Hibernate-specific and contain the entity instrumentation logic.

Comment: Hi, with `hibernate-core`, do i need: `hibernate-entitymanager`, `hibernate-validator`, `hibernate-validator-annotation-processor`, `hibernate-commons-annotations`, `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` and `hibernate-ehcache` dependencies ?

Comment: Those dependencies are like plug-ins. They provide additional functionality.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, how do i know if i need them or `hibernate-core` is enough?

Comment: The [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) explains what's the goal of each module. Enjoy reading it as much as I enjoyed writing it.

Comment: For Gradle users, use `implementation` instead of `compile`, beacause it is `@Depricated`.

Answer (score 4):

The official documentation (starting in 5.1) for bytecode enhancement is actually the [User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-enhancement-gradle).  That document still does not mention applying this plugin, as we assume some basic Gradle knowledge to use Gradle ;)  But it probably is better for that User Guide section to specify how to apply the plugin also (I created [an issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10552) in Jira for that).

In the meantime, the name of the id of the plugin is `org.hibernate.orm`, so you'd add:

```
apply: 'org.hibernate.orm'
```