# Apply hibernate-gradle-plugin using plugins dsl syntax?

Tags: hibernate, gradle, kotlin

I want to use `org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin` in my project with plugins dsl style. This is my `build.gradle.kts` plugin section:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.5.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version "1.3.31"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.3.31"
}
```

Does anybody knows how to do this?

All of the documentation and posts are using the legacy plugin application. Like this: [How to setup Hibernate Gradle plugin for bytecode enhancement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552109/how-to-setup-hibernate-gradle-plugin-for-bytecode-enhancement)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like they haven't registered this plugin in the [Gradle Plugins Repository](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=hibernate) which rules out using the newer DSL without using a custom [plugin resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_resolution_rules).

For your case in `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("org.hibernate.orm") version "5.4.3.Final"
}
```

And in `settings.gradle.kts`

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin { 
            if (requested.id.id == "org.hibernate.orm") { 
                useModule("org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}") 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, resolution startegy solved my problem. I wrote this in build.gradle.kts `id("org.hibernate.orm") version "5.4.3.Final"` and this to `settings.gradle.kts` `resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.hibernate.orm") {
                useModule("org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @aszik.k awesome! Glad you got it working. I'll add that to the answer for completeness

Comment: Does this work? I don't get any information in the console that the feature is enabled

Comment: Thanks. It seems that with Gradle version 6.6.1, the `resolutionStrategy` in `settings.gradle.kts` need to be wrapped in `pluginManagement { ... }` to work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the perfectly working solution of *@MarkRobbo* you can use the following snippet to configure the options of the `hibernate-gradle-plugin` in `build.gradle.kts`

```
tasks.withType<org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.EnhanceTask>().configureEach {
     options.enableLazyInitialization = true
}
```