# Use Hibernate Gradle plugin to transform legacy hbm.xml files

Tags: hibernate, gradle-plugin

We have a very old legacy project using lots of hbb.xml files and Hibernate6 complains about them.
I found that [hibernate gradle plugin](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/main/tooling/hibernate-gradle-plugin) promises to be able to transform them, but it is not yet documented.

I found a [TransformHbmXmlTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552109/how-to-setup-hibernate-gradle-plugin-for-bytecode-enhancement), but I did not found how to instrument it from gradle.